# Removing contents of bracelets

Tags: regex, r, data-manipulation

We have a free text:

```
sal{del{rf}ghladfs}wds{w12rf}qq
```

Output should be:

```
salwdsqq
```

Please share various approaches if possible. For example : lapply, gsub, for/while loop, grep

Comment: Please [edit] the question and tell what the relation is between your input and desired output. I can guess, but it's up to you to write good questions. The less people have to puzzle what you mean, the better your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Which language are you using ? This is very vague.

Comment: Are you missing one opening `{` or is the text correct as is?

Comment: @FredA., probably R since it's tagged with it

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/546433/1191259

Comment: I don't think a regex in R is going to help unless it supports recursion for matching balanced text. You could do your own functional recursion though since you only have two types `{}` and alnum's.

Answer (score 1):

This works in R

```
string1 <- "sal{del{rf}ghla}dfs}wds{w12rf}qq"
string2 <- gsub("{[^{}}]*}", "", string1, perl = TRUE)
string3 <- gsub("{.*}", "", string2, perl = TRUE)
string3
```

Comment: I think you have an extra closing bracket in `[^{}}]`

Comment: plz see the edited question. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: This answer also works fine with balanced brackets, like `s <- "sal{{del{rf}ghla}dfs}wds{w12rf}qq"` and in this case has a recursive extension: `s2 <- s; while(grepl("{[^{}]*}", s2, perl = TRUE)) s2 <- gsub("{[^{}]*}", "", s2, perl = TRUE)` @user3142384 Also, it seems to still work fine after your change to the question...

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work whether you had balanced or unbalanced brackets:

unbalanced (as in the q)

```
x <- "sal{del{rf}ghla}dfs}wds{w12rf}qq  "
paste0(gsub('\\w+}|[{} ]', '', strsplit(x, '\\{\\w+')[[1]]), collapse = '')
# [1] "salwdsqq"
```

inserted one randomly

```
x <- "sal{del{{rf}ghla}dfs}wds{w12rf}qq  "
paste0(gsub('\\w+}|[{} ]', '', strsplit(x, '\\{\\w+')[[1]]), collapse = '')
# [1] "salwdsqq"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a recursive regular expression.

```
x <- 'sal{del{rf}{sfddfdffdf}ghladfs}wds{w12rf}qq'
gsub('{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*+}', '', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "salwdsqq"
```